# In purr 'group_map', how to keep group information in the result

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

In 'group_map', how to add group information to the result list ?
As attached image, the result list include three tibble ,how to add group information (6/4/8) to seperate tibble ?  (`mtcars$cyl %>% unique()` > '6 4 8')

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  group_map(~ head(.,2))
```

[image]

Comment: what about adding the argument `.keep = TRUE` ?

Comment: @Edo  this is what I want , Thanks!